# Google Sheets Script to import data based on cell value and not duplicate information

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to pull/import data from "sheet 1" to "sheet 2" based on column 4 being a specific text string. The script should not pull lines that already exist.

I have no idea if this is possible. I can pull the data but it just recopies everything so I have duplicates.

Any help would be super appreciated.

```
function onEdit() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ognzsi6C0DU_ZyDLuct58f5U16sshhBpBoQ8Snk8bhc');
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); 
      var testrange = sheet.getRange('D:D');
      var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
      var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var csh = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
      var data = [];
      var j =[];
    
      
    for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
      if ( testvalue[i] == 'Dan') {
      data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,11).getValues());
      
      j.push(i);
      }
     }
    
     csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    
}
```

- [Sheet 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ognzsi6C0DU_ZyDLuct58f5U16sshhBpBoQ8Snk8bhc/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Sheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yOKiCfkUbIIhjTjnVdSnPVY8cY6WBkwwskTzZVcv4zk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. How do you want to run the script? In your script, `onEdit()` is used. But the simple trigger cannot use `openById`. 2. Can you provide the sample input and output you expect?

Comment: I fit could happen automatically that would be amazing. otherwise, I am okay just running it I could make a custom menu item. Thank for looking at it

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that you want to run the script from the custom menu. As the additional information, can you provide the sample input and output you expect in order to correctly understand about your question?

Comment: I would make a custom menu with an import function to pull the data I need from sheet 1 over to sheets 2 based on the selection in column 4. So everything assigned to dan will go to sheet 2. I hope that helps thanks again

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

You should be able to replace your code with this and it will work. You would put this script in the target sheet (Sheet 2), and replace the ID in the first line of the function with the origin (Sheet 1).

I'll leave it up to you to change to an `onEdit` or to make it a menu item. Right now it can be run from the script editor. `onEdit` doesn't make sense to me as an appropriate trigger. Maybe you prefer a [Time-Driven Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Though a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) would be the best way IMO.

```js
function pullData() {
    var sourceSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('[YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID]');
    var sourceRange = sourceSs.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
    var sourceHeight = sourceRange.getHeight();
    var sourceWidth = sourceRange.getWidth();
    var sourceData = sourceSs.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1, sourceHeight - 1, sourceWidth).getValues();

    var targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var targetRange = targetSs.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
    var targetHeight = targetRange.getHeight();
    var targetWidth = targetRange.getWidth();

    var sourceDataChecker = [];
    var targetDataChecker = [];

    sourceData.forEach((row) => {
        sourceDataChecker.push(row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + row[3]);
    })

    if (targetHeight != 1) {
        var targetData = sourceSs.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2, 1, targetHeight - 1, targetWidth).getValues();
        targetData.forEach((row) => {
            targetDataChecker.push(row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + row[3]);
        });
    };

    sourceData.forEach((row, i) => {
        if (!(targetDataChecker.includes(sourceDataChecker[i]))) {
            targetSs.appendRow(row);
        };
    });
}
```

#### Explanation

This script builds an "index" of each row in both sheets by concatenating all the values in the row. I did this because I noticed that sometimes you have "joe" in two rows, and so, you can't simply use column 4 as your index. You are basically checking for any row that is different from one in the target sheet (Sheet 2).

If the target sheet is blank, then all rows are copied.

#### References

- [Append Row to end of sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [Get Data Range (range of sheet that contains data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [Get Range Height (to deal with headers)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getheight)
- [Get Range Width](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getwidth)
- [for Each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you so much for this it seems to work but is pulling all data instead of just the one row with the specific text string.
I updated this portion with my text string
var sourceDataChecker = [];
var targetDataChecker = [];

Comment: Basically want to make it so all of one persons records goes to their sheet

Comment: I am a bit confused, sorry. You say that you want just **one** row with the specific text string in column 4 (column D), for example "joe", right? Yet in your example (Sheet 1) there are **two** rows with the value "joe" - so how should the script know which one to pull? There is also "Dan" and "dan" for instance. Can you please clarify this for me?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. If the line says dan i want it to pull that row to the sheet but not pull the rest. Then as more rows are added if they say dan they will be pull but it will not pull the previously pulled ones so no duplicates

Comment: Thanks, please just confirm 3 more things:

Can you confirm that you want only the **most recent** line to be pulled? Or if two or more rows have "Dan" - how do you know which one to pull? From the date? From how low it is in the sheet?

Can you confirm that you want the most recent line to **replace** the line in "Sheet 2"? So that you always only have **one row** for "Dan" or "Joe". Is that correct?

Do you want to distinguish between "dan" and "Dan" or are they the same?

Can you please update your **original question** with this information, thank you.

Comment: 1. Yes the most recent line for Dan to be pulled. These are just sample names but I would re use this script so all the people working with this sheet can pull only thier records to their personal sheet. 
2. When pulling I just don't want it to pull records for the person that that already have on thier sheet an duplicate them. 
3. Dan and Dan are the same it may have just been a typo in the sample.

Can't thank you enough for taking the time with this.

Comment: @CubbyG4M3R - please update your example in your original question. Below your question there is a button "edit". Use it to summarize the questions I have asked you. You still have not defined **how to tell which line is most recent** by its row number? Or by its date? In your example, the dates are the same...so how do you know which is more recent? **Please** update your original question with the info.

Comment: Also please refer to this: [Too Broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) - your question should be as focused as possible and should not simply be asking for code.